# "Half" independent edge sets in bipartite graphs

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Sorry if this is too basic. There is an idea like that of an independent edge set which occurs for bipartite graphs. I want to know the terminology for this concept and associated algorithms:

Let $G=(U,V,E)$ be a bipartite graph with edges $e \in E$ linking members of $U$ with members of $V.$ I say a set $S \subseteq E$ of edges is *$U$-independent* when each member of $U$ is touching (i.e., is an endpoint of) at most one member of $S.$

An example is shown here. The edges in $S$ are marked with red dashes. Notice that no member of $U$ is touching more than one member of $S.$

[image]

I have two questions:

1. Is there common terminology by which such *$U$-independent* sets of edges are more widely known ?
2. What is a good algorithm for finding all the $U$-independent sets of edges of a given $G$ ? (ideally I prefer simplicity over efficiency and also it would be great to have a reference).

Comment: While it'd be a bit more work, you might consider drawing out a small example of what such a graph and edge set would look like, and include it in your post.

Comment: Actually, here is a somewhat generic source of examples. We can interpret a bipartite graph as a binary relation on the members of $U$ and $V$. If we select a $U$-independent edge set, then these edges corresponds to a function from $U$ to $V$. (So [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function#/media/File:Not-Injection-Surjection.svg) would represent an $X$-independent set but not a $Y$-independent set.)

Comment: Indeed. I also added a picture like you suggested.

Comment: Correction: I think I should have said a _partial_ function, since it's possible that none of the edges in $S$ connect with some of the members of $U$. So I think the question could be posed as: Given a binary relation $R$ on $U,V$, how does one find all partial functions from $U$ to $V$ that contained in $R$? (In the sense of a binary relation as a set of ordered pairs.)

Comment: So a U-independent set corresponds to a partial function from U to V which is a sub-relation of E ? Yeah I suppose so. I was imagining the idea would be more mainstream to be honest. Also I am really hoping to get an algorithm to find these structures.

Comment: I guess for an algorithm, you just associate each node of U with a node of V it is linked to in E, or else "nothing". Each way to do this gives a U-independent set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128558/discussion-between-semiclassical-and-richard-southwell).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can generate all such structures simply by choosing, for each $u\in U$, either some edge incident to it, or to not pick any such edge.

Thus there are precisely $\prod_{u\in U} (d(u)+1)$ such structures in total.

Comment: In the case of $G$ being the complete bipartite graph $K_{m,n}$, this reduces to $(|V|+1)^{|U|}$ as it should